# получить список файлов в web директории

Tags: html

1. есть url http://nod32.serve.com/ если открыть его в браузере то по 301 будет переход на http://nod32.ru/ (url условные)
2. но! если ввести http://nod32.serve.com/ в настройки(доступ к обновлениям антивирусной базы) антивируса НОД32, то никакого перенаправления 301, НОД32 вссосет обновления антивирусной базы.

Вопрос: как на делфи такое реализовать, на основе какого компонента и вообще. если использовать Tidhttp (инди), то либо перенаправление на http://nod32.ru/, либо ничего

Заранее спасибо за ответы по ЗАДАННЫМ вопросам

Comment: Не очень понятна задача - вам нужно сделать серверную часть с редиректом? Или клиентскую с игнорированием редиректа? Или клиентскую с реакцией на редирект?